# Using highlight.js in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlight.js

My ember app is set up with a list of posts on the left and a view for an individual post on the right. When one of the posts on the left is clicked it's content is rendered in the view on the right.

This is the code I'm using to add syntax highlighting to a post.

```
App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
  }
});
```

When the first post view is rendered, it has the syntax highlighting, but when I click on a different post and it's content gets loaded into the post view the syntax highlighting does not get applied. How can I make it so that the highlighting applied every time a post is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess without a more comprehensive example. Is `PostView` what gets created in the right panel? If so, then you need to constrain your view rendering to the stuff inside the view.

In your example, `$('pre code')` will target all `pre code` elements inside the document. Try `this.$('pre code')`, or whatever element/selector needs to be highlighted within the view.

Comment: Yes, `PostView` is what gets created in the right panel. The issues is that the syntax highlighting only gets applied to the first post that is viewed in that panel. When you click on another and it gets loaded into the `PostView` the didInsertElement function does not run and so the post does not have syntax highlighting. I hope that makes the question more clear.

Comment: There's no way to tell without more code. I suggest you try to isolate the problem and put some toy example on jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not the cleanest way to do the job, but you could try adding observer to the controller's model, and make required changes. But this will only work, if the model itself changes.

Like this:

```
postHasChanged: function() {
    if (this.get('state') === 'inDOM') {
        $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(e)
        });
    }
}.observes('controller.model')
```

Comment: I put this snippet into `App.PostView` and the highlighting doesn't get applied. Should it be `this.$('pre code').each....`? When I change it to that an error gets thrown `Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
    at null.postHasChanged (http://localhost:3000/assets/app.js:16:23)`

Comment: You need to make sure that the view state is `inDOM`, so it can access the rendered elements.

Comment: I tried this and this.get('state') never has the value of 'inDom'

Comment: It is `inDOM` rather than `inDom`